# Unable to get name of the group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a name of the group with below code

```
Get-ADGroup | Where-Object name -like "#GG-GG-O365-GG"
```

But it always asking me to filter it.

```
cmdlet Get-ADGroup at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Filter: *
```

What criteria should I add to find the name?

Comment: `Get-ADGroup` must be called with one of the required parameters `-Identity`, `-Filter`, or `-LDAPFilter`. When calling the cmdlet without named parameters the first positional parameter (or input from the pipeline) goes to the parameter `-Identity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below cmdlet `Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "*GG-GG-O365-GG*"}`. `*` is wildcard.

Comment: You can run `Get-Help about_ActiveDirectory_Filter` to get more information about how to construct these filter expressions.